# Why are class namespaces special in Python

Tags: python, scoping

```
var_a = 0

class Chunk:
    var_a = 1

    def __init__(self):
        print("Global a = {}".format(var_a))
        print("Local a = {}".format(self.var_a))

mychunk = Chunk()
```

The result of this is:

```
Global a = 0                                                                                                                                     
Local a = 1
```

Another example

```
class BadIdea:
    var_b = 0
    def bad_idea(self):
        var_b = 1;
        nonlocal var_b
        print("var_b = {}".format(var_b))

whoops = BadIdea()
```

gives

```
main.py:25: SyntaxWarning: name 'var_b' is assigned to before nonlocal declaration                                                               
  nonlocal var_b                                                                                                                                 
  File "main.py", line 25                                                                                                                        
    nonlocal var_b                                                                                                                               
SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'var_b' found
```

As @chepner pointed out for the latter example, the non-local scope doesn't contain `var_b` as the class scope doesn't exist?

I'm still curious why the "class scope" is somehow different than a function scope.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The local variable is not visible outside its method because, well, it's local.

Comment: This has nothing to do with class scope, indeed, `undef_b = 5` is **not happening in the class scope**, it is happening in the *function scope*, i.e. the local scope of `add_local` ... it is a local variable, and thus it is local. Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: This isn't really about the class's non-scope status; its just a demonstration of function-local scope versus global scope.

Comment: However, the question *does* become more interesting if you declare `undef_b` to be non-local and add a class attribute named `undef_b`. You'll immediately get a syntax error because there is no nonlocal `undef_b`.

Comment: function/method shoud get values in arguments and uses `return` to send back values - it shouldn't change external values because it only makes problem. If it changes external variables (which is called "side effect") then you can accidently change external variable and it could be hard to find problem. You would have to create unique names in function  to make sure you don't change external variable. i.e you couldn't use the same name `x` in all functions but you would have to use i.e `function1_x`, `function2_x`, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry for the original example, which as everyone pointed out was nonsensical. I fixed my code example. Thank you.